# How does formatting works with a PowerShell function that returns a set of elements?

Tags: powershell

If I write this small function :

```
function Foo {
    Get-Process | % { $_ } 
}
```

And if I run

```
Foo
```

It displays only a small subset of properties:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> foo

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
     86      10     1680        412    31     0,02   5916 alg
    136      10     2772       2356    78     0,06   3684 atieclxx
    123       7     1780       1040    33     0,03    668 atiesrxx
...
...
```

But even if only 8 columns are shown, there are plenty of other properties (as `foo | gm` is showing).

What is causing this function to show only this 8 properties?

I'm actually trying to build a similar function that is returning complex objects from a 3rd party .Net library. The library is flatting a 2 level hierarchy of objects :

```
function Actual {

    $someDotnetObject.ACollectionProperty.ASecondLevelCollection | % { $_ }

}
```

This method is dumping the objects in a list form (one line per property).

How can I control what is displayed, **keeping the actual object available**?

I have tried this :

```
function Actual {

    $someDotnetObject.ACollectionProperty.ASecondLevelCollection | % { $_ } | format-table Property1, Property2

}
```

It shows in a console the expected table :

```
Property1  Property2
---------  ---------
     ValA       ValD
     ValB       ValE
     ValC       ValF
```

But I lost my objects. Running `Get-Member` on the result shows :

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData

Name                                    MemberType Definition                                                                              
----                                    ---------- ----------                                                                              
Equals                                  Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                          
GetHashCode                             Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                       
GetType                                 Method     type GetType()                                                                          
ToString                                Method     string ToString()                                                                       
autosizeInfo                            Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.AutosizeInfo autosizeInfo {get;set;}      
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd Property   System.String ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd {get;}                            
groupingEntry                           Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupingEntry groupingEntry {get;set;}    
pageFooterEntry                         Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.PageFooterEntry pageFooterEntry {get;set;}
pageHeaderEntry                         Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.PageHeaderEntry pageHeaderEntry {get;set;}
shapeInfo                               Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ShapeInfo shapeInfo {get;set;}            


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData

Name                                    MemberType Definition                                                                          
----                                    ---------- ----------                                                                          
Equals                                  Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                      
GetHashCode                             Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                   
GetType                                 Method     type GetType()                                                                      
ToString                                Method     string ToString()                                                                   
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd Property   System.String ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd {get;}                        
groupingEntry                           Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupingEntry groupingEntry {get;set;}
shapeInfo                               Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ShapeInfo shapeInfo {get;set;}
```

Instead of showing the 2nd level child object members. In this case, I can't pipe the result to functions waiting for this type of argument.

How does Powershell is supposed to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually controlled by format files. From powershell `help about_Format.ps1xml`:

> The Format.ps1xml files in Windows PowerShell define the default display
>      of objects in Windows PowerShell. You can create your own Format.ps1xml
>      files to change the display of objects or to define default displays
>      for new object types that you create in Windows PowerShell.
>
> When Windows PowerShell displays an object, it uses the data in structured
>      formatting files to determine the default display of the object. The
>      data in the formatting files determines whether the object is rendered in
>      a table or in a list, and it determines which properties are displayed by
>      default.
>
> The formatting affects the display only. It does not affect which object
>      properties are passed down the pipeline or how they are passed.

As per your example, `get-process` returns `System.Diagnostics.Process`, which (format of output) is defined in `DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml`:

```
    <Name>process</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>System.Diagnostics.Process</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>
    <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Handles</Label>
                <Width>7</Width>
                <Alignment>right</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>NPM(K)</Label>
                <Width>7</Width>
                <Alignment>right</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
(output omitted)
```

Comment: I'll have to play a bit with this files. This looks like to be the solution. I'll report soon if it is.

Comment: This actually worked. The only missing part, is the ability to autosize the output columns. Is there any equivalent of `Format-Table -Autosize` that can be setup in this file (this may be a new question on superuser) ?

Comment: You could try <AutoSize/> as specified here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg580906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Those: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/06/21/more-how-does-powershell-formatting-really-work.aspx contain a lot of useful info as well

Comment: I missed that. Thank you very much, I've learned a lot of useful things today :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host $_.Something
  $_
}
```

The trailing `$_` inside the code block passes the object.

Comment: Won't this double the output? Both the property and the object itself?

Comment: Try `$foo = ... | % { Write-Host $_.Something; $_ }` or `... | % { Write-Host $_.Something; $_ } > output.txt`. The output of `Write-Host` always goes directly to the host, it's not processed any further.