# How do I force output to "Format-Table" for a custom PSObject WITHOUT using a .format.ps1xml file?

Tags: powershell, script

I know that I can define formatting for my `MyCustomPSObject` by generating and loading a `MyCustomPSObject.format.ps1xml` file.

And I have seen [people do this format-file-generation on-the-fly from inside the .ps1-script file.](https://archive.is/Zwwid#selection-1337.0-1459.4) (Also here starting [listing below the sentence *"So I wrote an advanced PowerShell function called Get-ProcessTotal"* starting on line 145](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/3718/theres-sum-thing-happening-here/).)

And, from what I understand, [the first entry in that formatting file is used as the default.](https://archive.is/JOIDL#selection-5989.0-5989.121)

Generating that external file seems cumbersome to me.

#### Question:

- Is there a way to do this WITHOUT generating and loading that external file?

All I want is *"Output it as a table"*. (Basically running it through `Format-Table` but not losing object-ness in the process.)

#### Related question

- [How does formatting works with a PowerShell function that returns a set of elements?](https://superuser.com/questions/469980/how-does-formatting-works-with-a-powershell-function-that-returns-a-set-of-eleme)

#### Script Get-VSSWriters.Current-Version.ps1

This is the script in question:

```
# This script lists VSS writers.
# The original, uncustomized, version was taken from here:
# https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-ScriptFunction-415e9e70

$RawWriters = Invoke-Command -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
    #Requires -RunAsAdministrator 
    return (VssAdmin List Writers)
} 


# We don't really care about "WriterID" and "WriterInstanceID", so we leave them out of the default 
# display set. (Approach copied from here:
# https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/ )
$defaultDisplaySet = 'WriterEnum', 'WriterName', 'StateID', 'StateDesc', 'LastError'
$defaultDisplayPropertySet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet('DefaultDisplayPropertySet', [string[]]$defaultDisplaySet)
$PSStandardMembers = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]@($defaultDisplayPropertySet)


$Writers = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt (($RawWriters.Count)-3)/6; $i++) {
    $Writer = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $Writer.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0, 'MyVSSWriter')
    $Writer | Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers

    $Writer| Add-Member "WriterEnum" ($i + 1)

    # Note: We split on both single quotes and double quotes.
    # That way this script will work for both:
    # * the English language version of Windows (>>Writer name: 'WMI Writer'<<) 
    # * the German version of Windows (>>Verfassername: "WMI Writer"<<)
    $Writer| Add-Member "WriterName" $RawWriters[($i*6)+3].Split("`"'")[1]

    $Writer| Add-Member "WriterID" $RawWriters[($i*6)+4].Split('{}')[1]
    $Writer| Add-Member "WriterInstanceID" $RawWriters[($i*6)+5].Split('{}')[1]

    $Writer| Add-Member "StateID"   $RawWriters[($i*6)+6].Split('[]')[1]
    $Writer| Add-Member "StateDesc" $RawWriters[($i*6)+6].Split('[]')[2].SubString(1)
    $Writer| Add-Member "LastError" $RawWriters[($i*6)+7].Split(':')[1].Substring(1)

    $Writers += $Writer 
}

$Writers
```

#### Actual output

```
PS C:\> .\Get-VSSWriters.Current-Version.ps1 | select -first 1
WriterEnum : 1
WriterName : Task Scheduler Writer
StateID    : 1
StateDesc  : Stable
LastError  : No error
```

#### Desired output

```
PS C:\> .\Get-VSSWriters.Updated-Version.ps1 | select -first 1
WriterEnum WriterName            StateID StateDesc LastError
---------- ----------            ------- --------- ---------
         1 Task Scheduler Writer 1       Stable    No error
```

(Which should be the same as `.\Get-VSSWriters.Current-Version.ps1 | select -first 1 | Format-Table`.)

Comment: [Usually objects are displayed in tabular form when they have up to 4 properties, and in list form when they have more than 4 properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344479/3439404)

Comment: @JosefZ: Yeah. But this table has 5 properties and still it's in "List" format.

Comment: Your object is just a list of noteproperties, it's not a table or a list.  Powershell decides to display it as a list or table depending on the number of noteproperties. 4 or less: displays as table. More than 4: display as list.  Your object has 5 noteproperties so will display as a list by default.    If you do find a cmdlet that has 5 or more columns and displays as a table, let me know it would be good to see how it's done.

Comment: @MarkHeath: Yes. I agree and I realize that this is how it works. But I don't like it. ^^ And I was looking for a simple way to change that. (Actually I think I'm annoyed with how any of the Format-* cmdlets work. Why do they take a way object-ness? Seems wrong.)

Comment: Their reasoning assumes that the need for formatting and the need for objects are mutually exclusive. If you're using it in a pipeline then it doesn't need formatting.   If the data requires formatting then it is the last step when presenting data to the user.   I'd be curious to know if you know of a use case where both formatting and object passing is required.