# Format-List does not show access list from Get-Acl

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of files, their owners and permissions

```
PS C:\> echo Windows | Get-Acl |Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows
Owner  : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
Group  : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
Access : CREATOR OWNER Allow  268435456
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  268435456
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  Modify, Synchronize
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  268435456
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  Modify, Synchronize
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  -1610612736
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller Allow  268435456
         NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller Allow  FullControl
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  -1610612736
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464G:S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-185
         3292631-2271478464D:PAI(A;OICIIO;GA;;;CO)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;SY)(A;;0x1301bf;;;SY)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;BA)(A;;0x1301bf;;;
         BA)(A;OICIIO;GXGR;;;BU)(A;;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;CIIO;GA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271
         478464)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464)(A;;0x1200a9;;;AC)(A;OICIIO;GXG
         R;;;AC)
```

I thought to filter `Audit` and `Sddl` using the `-Property` argument, but that does not show the `Access` properly:

```
PS C:\> echo Windows | Get-Acl |Format-List -Expand Both -Property Path, Owner, Group, Access


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows
Owner  : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
Group  : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
Access : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule,
         System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule...}
```

How do I get it to list the access rule?

Comment: You could insert `Select -Expandproperty Access|` before `Format-List` but Access is a list not a single property so you might not get what you expect...

Comment: `echo $env:SystemRoot | Get-Acl | Select-Object -Property * -ExpandProperty Access`

Comment: @JosefZ that seems to print the same things again and again: `echo $env:SystemRoot | Get-Acl | Select-Object -Property * -ExpandProperty Access | findstr PSPath` prints `PSPath                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows` 11 times.

Comment: `dir $env:SystemRoot\*.log | foreach { $_ | Get-Acl | select -Property Owner, Path -ExpandProperty Access}` gives list of files (merely `.log` for brevity), their owners and expanded `Access`. Maybe creating a custom `psobject` like in http://superuser.com/questions/1173588 would lead to desired result more easily.